# How Does WebSphere Choose the Classloading Order in a Folder (WEB-INF/lib)

Tags: java, class, websphere, classloader

I am currently facing an interesting problem where our application fails to start up on 3/4 nodes due to classloading issues.

The problem seems to be that WAS is loading b.jar before a.jar. After troubleshooting more, I found that all of the nodes load the jars in different orders (via Classpath viewer in console) and the working node may have just been a fluke.

How does WebSphere determine the classloading order within an installed applications WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: During startup are you getting class not found exception?

Comment: Not quite.. i'm getting another error and when discussed with the developer he says that it is because it is loading a certain jar our of order. There is a 0-jarname.jar that they intended to load before jarname.jar however on 3/4 nodes, it loads jarname.jar before 0-jarname.jar. I'm trying to understand how it loads the order since in the websphere classpath viewer it doesn't seem to have any meaningful order.

Comment: is there any reason why 0-jarname.jar and jarname.jar cannot simply be combined into a single jar?

Comment: You state "application fails to start up" can you post the error? And why would it make a difference whether b.jar or a.jar are loaded first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of loading jars is undefined in websphere. To solve your problem I can suggest  you to use one of the below option.

Use manifest classpath settings by mentioning the jar names in a order like how you want them to be loaded.

**OR**

You can extract the classes from a.jar and put it in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory. Then remove a.jar from the lib folder. Because `classes` directory will be loaded before `lib` directory.

Comment: Thank you. I will be trying the first option shortly and will probably ask the developer to help with option 2 if needed.

Comment: Ok.Good luck :)

Comment: Actually one question.. when setting the Class-path: in the manifest file.. if I were to want to look in the installedApps/[appname]/WEB-INF/lib/jarname.jar, what would be the relative path? Would WEB-INF/lib/jarname.jar be sufficient?

Comment: Usually we will refer like `global\a.jar` and `global` is a directory available in the ear but not inside the war. I am not sure about referring jar inside `WEB-INF\lib`.

Comment: It is not possible to use Class-Path to control the order of WEB-INF/lib (so that is somewhat of a non-option).

Comment: the first option will not work, as @BrettKail pointed out.  The second will work, although I would recommend simply combining all jars in WEB-INF/lib into one jar, instead of extracting the library classes into the WEB-INF/classes directory.

Comment: As @BrettKail mentioned, #1 did not work. I confirmed that we cannot reference the WEB-INF/lib in the manifests Class-Path. #2 did work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can configure the classloader in Websphere, PARENT_FIRST (default) or PARENT_LAST. Classloaders in Websphere are hierarchical, you can think of it as a tree where you have:
Java class loader -> ext class loader -> App module class loader -> web module class loader

PARENT_FIRST will load classes from the "top down" starting with the Java class loaders, whereas PARENT_LAST will load the classes from the "bottom up" starting with the web module class loader. If you are using open source libraries that conflict with WAS-shipped libraries, I would suggest that you use PARENT_LAST.

Take a look at these resources for more info:

- http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/crun_classload.html
- http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/urun_rclassloader_inst.html

Comment: Thank you for the feedback but not quite what I was asking for. I am using parent last since I want the web modules classes first however within the web module WEB-INF/lib folder, I wanted to figure out how the classes were loaded in that folder (which appears to be undocumented).