# IWAE0008E An error occurred reading jar file

Tags: java, spring, websphere

We have a war file that uses java, spring etc. I have to deploy this war file in Websphere 9. I had setup datasource. I am getting the following error when I try to deploy the war file.

com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.NestedJarException: IWAE0008E An error occurred reading WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-5.0.16.RELEASE.jar from /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/wstemp/92668751/upload/awdcs.war [Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.NestedJarException: IWAE0008E An error occurred reading WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-5.0.16.RELEASE.jar from /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/wstemp/92668751/upload/awdcs.war]

[image]

Any thoughts on what is causing this issue and how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a class-loading order issue. Try changing the order from parent_first to parent_last from the settings of the server. Check out [How Does WebSphere Choose the Classloading Order in a Folder (WEB-INF/lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424458/how-does-websphere-choose-the-classloading-order-in-a-folder-web-inf-lib) and https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/crun_classload.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if the jar dependency "spring-context-5.0.16.RELEASE.jar" is part of the war file "awdcs.war". You can unzip the WAR file and inspect.

Make sure the jar is included in the war when it is built or worst-case add the jar as part of the websphere runtime.

Answer (score 0):

My case was with spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, the solution for me was extract of WEB-INF/lib and put in classes/spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar. Was necesary delete of lib